# How to remove the warning "the counter will not be printed" when using enumerate package for itemized list?

Tags: enumerate

Here, as in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[$\bullet$]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The `{enumerate}` package enhanced `enumerate` environment will cause a warning during compilation "the counter will not be printed". Is there a way to remove the warning without modifying the package?

Comment: @David Carlisle  Dear David, you are the author...will you...

Comment: It's only a warning, nothing else... And you could use `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` instead

Comment: @David Carlisle, I am not sure what the purpose of this warning. Do we get this because `\bullet + 1` does not make any sense, that is, it is impossible to increment its value for consecutive `\item`-s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get rid off easily, use `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` as a replacement.

But the easiest way is just to use `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` instead of `enumerate`, if the only cause for this use is the `\bullets`.

See that `\begin{enumerate}[$\bullet$]` and `\begin{enumerate}[label={$\bullet$}]` are equal.

If `enumerate` package is the only option: It's only a warning, nothing more, nothing less in this sense.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

Using traditional enumerate package:

\begin{enumerate}[\textbullet]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

With itemize environment:

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}

And again with explicit labels:

\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbullet]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: `\textbullet` might be better!

Comment: Thx alot man. I was just not familiar with all the packages I suppose. I never finished reading latex companion. Now I am going through the texbook first...

Answer (score 1):

The default enumerations are [a] (for alphabetical enumeration), [i] (for roman enumeration), and [1] (for arabic/numeric enumeration).  Although this may seem cumbersome, but `\item[<->]` instead of `\item` removed the errors for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Using traditional enumerate package:

\begin{enumerate}[\textbullet]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

With itemize environment:

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}

And again with explicit labels: 

\begin{enumerate}
\item[a.] one
\item[b.] two
\item[c.] three
\end{enumerate}

Some more text

%%% Here's what I did - individual labeling %%%
\begin{enumerate}
\item[d.] four
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Especially when one is making a presentation or a long-text enumeration, many a times the list can overflow on the next page.  One can start a new `\begin{enumerate}` - `\end{enumerate}`, but the desired numbering might get lost as `enumerate` counter is reset to 1 on every run/occasion.  So individual label naming is what suits best.

Using `itemize` simply gets rid of the numbers, and provides the default bullet.  Also the item labels are customizable in `enumerate`.